# Add lombok plugin to IntelliJ 12.1.4. on Mac

Tags: macos, intellij-idea, lombok

I'm just trying to add the Lombok plugin to IntelliJ IDEA 12.1.4. on a Mac machine, see:

The documentation on this page (https://code.google.com/p/lombok-intellij-plugin/) said:

> ...just download, unzip to IntelliJ plugin directory and try out!

First I had to use EasyFind to find out this folder, because it was invisible...

than I put the plugin at the directory:

> ~/Library/Application Support/IntelliJIdeaXX

as specified on this page (http://devnet.jetbrains.com/docs/DOC-181), and redeployed the app. But the code keeps showing compile errors on every line that uses Lombok's features, even the simple **@Getter** and **@Setter** annotations.

so I've restarted the IDE, the highlighted compile time errors were gone, but when I run it on Glassfish it caught the compile time error, on the same line of code: trying to get a property using getter method that is generated by Lombok.

**Exception:**

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous tree type: <any>
at com.codepianist.model.Model.<clinit>(Model.java:40)
... 50 more
```

**Error:**

```
// Error code
@Getter
private static Map<String, Language> LANGUAGES_MAP = new HashMap();
static {
    for(Language l : LANGUAGES)
        LANGUAGES_MAP.put(l.getId(), l); // line 40
}
```

**Language Class:**

```
// Language class
public class Language implements Serializable{

    public Language(){}

    public Language(String id, String flag) {
        this.id = id;
        this.flag = flag;
        this.locale =  new Locale(id);
    }

    @Getter private String id;
    @Getter private String flag;
    @Getter private Locale locale;

}
```

**For information**: Tried to call **mvn clean install -e** from my Terminal and not a single error. And the same app, runs fine with Netbeans.

May I have to configure the plugin on any IDE section?

I'm migrating from Netbeans, and just installed IntelliJ IDE, so I'm pretty new to it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

Try installing the plugin using the following guide: http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/open_api_plugin_manager.html